# SBT 1.0+ Resolvers no longer using Credentials?

Tags: sbt, azure-devops, sbt1.0, azure-artifacts

this is related to the last question I posted on the subject:

[SBT Publish to Visual Studio Team Services (Web) Packages Plugin Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46412999/3392246)

At the time I wrote that I was running SBT 0.13.16, and was able to make everything work.

My team has attempted since then to upgrade to SBT 1.0.x, and while for a while it seemed to work, it turns out that was only thanks to the cached versions of our libraries in ivy.

Attempting a clean setup using the same technique that worked in SBT 0.13.16 results in no attempt to send authentication information to the servers (and thus, no library download and frustrated devs); verified with Fiddler.

**PUBLISHING** does work and seems to make proper use of the credentials, but **DEPENDENCY RESOLUTION** does not, any longer.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how I can replicate the old behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean resolving?

Comment: @tear Specifically "dependency resolution".  I'll update the question with that phrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was resolved at some point before sbt 1.1.6.

Comment: This is just of comment quality answer

Comment: This is true, but I also don't care enough to keep researching it since my problem is gone and I was pursuing it for work.  They won't pay me to find out why problems aren't problems anymore.

Additionally I had waited 4 months without any other interest from anyone.  I just wanted closure here in case someone else looked.  If a better solution is offered that actually explains it I'll happily make that the real solution.